# using spark-avro to write dataframe creates topLevelRecord - want to use existing schema

Tags: java, apache-spark, record, avro

I am encoding GenericRecords into a spark DataFrame using A Kryo encoder, and I am writing the dataframe to an Avro file. Once I try to read the file from Hive, I get an error saying that the parser finds the toplevelrecord instead of the expected field. This record isn't in my existing schema and I think its getting created when I use spark-avro to write. I want to know if/how I can remove this from the avro file.

This is what it looks like:

```
{
    "type":"record",
    "name":"topLevelRecord",
    "fields":[
         {
            "name":"value",
            "type":["bytes","null"]
         }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The name field is **required** in an Avro Schema (https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-AvroOptions.html)

The value **topLevelRecord** is the default one if one isn't set in the schema, however you can provide a value to override it when you write the data frame.

Scala:
Create a parameters map and pass it to the writer:

```
val name = "AvroTest"
val parameters = Map("recordName" -> name)
df.write.options(parameters).format("avro").save("/tmp/output")
```

Ref: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-avro.html

Python:
Pass an option to the writer as follows:

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").option("recordName", "Uber").save("tmp/output")
```